# How to hide a full path to source file when importing TypeScript symbols from an external library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have [@ts-stack/mod](https://github.com/ts-stack/mod) module which internally exports `ColumnsDecoratorFactory`, but for public API I want to export only `ORM` symbol to usage it this way:

```ts
import { ORM } from '@ts-stack/mod';

ORM.ColumnsDecoratorFactory // I just want to have access this way
```

Can direct import `ColumnsDecoratorFactory` be banned?

```ts
// VS Code offers me to import from these places, I don't want to see it:

import { ColumnsDecoratorFactory } from '@ts-stack/mod/dist/modules/orm/decorators/column';
// OR
import { ColumnsDecoratorFactory } from '@ts-stack/mod/dist/modules/orm';
```

I did the following on the `src/index.ts`:

```ts
import * as ORM from './modules/orm';
export { ORM };
```

My source files compiles from `src` to `dist` folder. In `package.json` I say:

```json
"main": "dist/index",
"types": "dist/index",
```

Comment: One possible "solution", but will just shift it to somewhere else is the usage of barrels [Angular 2 : Organization Using {barrels}](https://tattoocoder.com/angular2-barrels/), only the barrel file will be imported, and because you don't need to work in it, all of that is hidden away...

Comment: This might have to be tagged to a `Visual Studio Code` tag, as this seems like it might be an issue specific to that IDE, and not javascript/typescript in general.

Comment: @Evert, but it is possible that this can be done using the mechanism provided through JavaScript / TypeScript.